# Error in injecting a generic Command handler using IMediator .Net Core 2

Tags: generics, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, mediator

I am using IMediator with .Net Core 2.2 and I have a generic Command that I want to inject in the service collection:

```
public class GetByIdCommand<T> : IRequest<T>
{
     public GetByIdCommand(int id)
     {    
         this.Id = id;
     }

     public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the handler:

```
public class GetByIdCommandHandler<TFrom, TTo> : IRequestHandler<GetByIdCommand<TTo>, TTo>
{
    public GetByIdCommandHandler()
    {
        // Repository<TFrom>
    }

    public async Task<TTo> Handle(GetByIdCommand<TTo> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Get Model
    }
}
```

And the injection is like that:

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetByIdCommandHandler<,>).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

When I call the command:

```
var model = await this.Mediator.Send(new GetByIdCommand<DbModel, MyModel>(1)).AnyContext();
```

But I am getting this failure:

> InvalidOperationException: Handler was not found for request of type
>   MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[GetByIdCommand`1[MyModel],MyModel].
>   Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub
>   for examples.

I don't know why I am getting this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For `services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetByIdCommandHandler<,>).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);`, it would not help you register the created `GetByIdCommandHandler`, you need to register it by yourself.

Try code below in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), typeof(GetByIdCommandHandler<,>));
services.AddMediatR();
```

Comment: Hello @Tao, exactly this was the problem. I tried yesterday to make an implementation to the Command. GetStudentByIdCommandHandler and it worked for me. But I will try your solution today and I will inform back if it works. Thanks, anyway